# create own plugin

Tags: python, qgis-plugins

With the QGIS plugin 'plugin builder' I create a new plugin.

Then I followed the steps described on this website : http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html

It works perfect until step 18,

But when I pass the code of step 19 I receive the following error:

```
an deze plugin niet laden hond wegens een fout bij het aanroepen van de methode initGui() 

AttributeError: hond instance has no attribute 'run' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 315, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName].initGui()
  File "C:/Users/niels/.qgis2/python/plugins\hond\hond.py", line 167, in initGui
    callback=self.run,
AttributeError: hond instance has no attribute 'run'
```

However I didn't change anything in the 'gui' part...

Comment: Check your indentations.

Comment: Unable to look at the tutorial now but it sounds like you might have forgotten *self* as in *self*.run